# How do I pass real-time progress data to a chunk in Flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, flexdashboard

I have a large amount of r-code that reads data from Jira and other apps and then will eventually display the results using Flexdashboard/Shiny.  I can get the data to display OK, but what I'm looking for is a way to show the progress of the data load on a section of the dashboard while the data is loading.

I've simplified the code  showing just a single gauge and minimal dashboard. How can I get the changing variable 'amt' to update the gauge as it changes - hence, a proress bar of sorts?

````
---
title "Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

for (i in 1:100) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  amt <- reactive({i})
}

```
Progress
---------------------------

### Progress

```{r}
gaugeOuput("gauge1")
output$gauge1 = renderGauge({gauge(amt(), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%')})

```
````

Comment: You're missing a`:` in `title:"Test"`. Otherwise your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reactiveTimer()` for this:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global}
library(shiny)
rt <- reactiveTimer(1000)
rv <- reactiveVal(0)

observe({
  rt()
  tick = isolate(rv())
  if(tick < 100){
    rv(tick + 1)
  }
  else
    rt <- reactiveTimer(Inf)
})
```
Progress
---------------------------

### Progress

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
output$gauge1 = renderGauge({gauge(rv(), min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%')})
gaugeOutput("gauge1")
```
````

Comment: I see where this works, but how does it solve my problem?  The value of rv will be changing in the global context. My problem is that the gauge doesn't trigger until all the code in the global context has completed. My original sample code may be misleading in this regard. I need rv to be the % of jira data loaded and while the loading is still taking place the gauge gets updated periodically.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add a progress bar, although I don't think it's easy.  Scroll down to "A more complex Progress example": https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html. If you can figure it out and create a reprex, I'd be grateful!  I'll share again if I can find an example that works.

Edit: You can do this with the `shinybusy` package. Copying from their example:

```
fluidPage(add_busy_bar(color = "#86D0F9")) #make sure to add a color or it will
                                           #be clear and you won't see it

actionButton("go", "Submit")
```

Create your event reactive object

```
example <- eventReactive(input$go{
#some function
})
```

Then add this:

```
observeEvent(input$go, {
example()
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A link  is not really considered an answer. Have a look at [answer] or https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers for guidance .